# How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

So we have something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Brushless Motor Fundamentals}
\subsection{Brushless Motor Operation}
\subsubsection{DC Motor Operation}
Torque is generated in DC motors from the magnetic force,
also known as the Lorentz force, which is produced when an
electric current is passed through a coil in a magnetic field.
This force is given by $F=q[E+(v\times B)]$,
where $F$ is the force perpendicular to the coil,
$E$ is the electric field in the coil, $B$ is the magnetic field,
and $v$ is the velocity of the charged particles in the coil.
From mechanics, torque is $\tau=F\times r$.

\section{Brushless Motor Fundamentals 2}
\subsection{Brushless Motor Operation}
\subsubsection{DC Motor Operation 2}
If the electrical force is ignored and the remaining magnetic force is used,
with the assumption that $v$ is perpendicular to $B$,
we find that $\tau=qvBrsin\theta$.

\end{document}
```

How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?

Comment: What exactly do you mean ? Could you give us an example ? From what I understood you want to remove `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` from your preamble ?

Comment: I like your question, but the code is really cluttered with a lot of stuff that has nothing to do with your problem. Could you please reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) by removing everything that doesn't change your problem? As an example, you can leave out all the equations and the related stuff, and for text, a single word like `foo` or `bar` suffices entirely.

Comment: Related Question: [Hide subsubsections in toc, but show in PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68989/hide-subsubsections-in-toc-but-show-in-pdf).

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Increase the value of `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth`. The `tocdepth` value determines to which level the sectioning commands are printed in the ToC (they are always included in the `.toc` file but ignored otherwise). The `secnumdepth` value determines up to what level the sectioning titles are numbered. They are LaTeX counters and you can set them using `\setcounter`.

The sectioning levels have the following numbers:

```
-1 part
0 chapter     
1 section       
2 subsection  
3 subsubsection
4 paragraph
5 subparagraph
```

In the document class `article`, `\chapter` doesn't exist and `0` stands for `\part` instead.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oddly enough, in `scrreprt` this doesn't seem to work properly unless you set `secnumdepth` first.

Comment: For anyone interested to locate the definition on levels of headings, for builtin document classes, it is introduced in section "7.2.7 Lower level headings" in `classes.pdf` (accessible by command line `texdoc classes` or on CTAN), defined with the 2nd argument of the environment command `@startsection` .

Comment: @EgorHans This seems not to be correct. `tocdepth` (= showing an entry in the ToC) and `secnumdepth` (= numbering the heading and therefore also ToC entry) are independent in `scrreprt` like they are in `report`. BTW: With `scrreprt` you even don't need to know the absolute levels numbers (and maybe should not use them, because they are configurable). You can just use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{\paragraphtocdepth}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\paragraphnumdepth}`.

Comment: Be careful, you are mixing secnumdepth and tocdepth. 0 stands for \part only in secnumdepth. \l@part uses \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax and therefore setting tocdepth to -1 still shows the parts in the the ToC. So the tocdepth of part is -1.

Comment: @cabohah Maybe the issue you're pointing out (with the depth for a specific level being different between the counters) was the cause of having to set `secnumdepth` for me. If I ever go back to using that snippet for anything (I'm no longer in a situation where I need to write such documents any time soon), I'll definitely rewrite it to use the respective macros and see if I still need both.