# TOC does not create according to .toc file

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

Am I missing something?  I have headings from Chapter to Paragraph.  All of the Chapter, Section, and Subsection headings are listed in the printed TOC.  Nothing below Subsection prints in the TOC even though they are in the .toc file.

I have `.toc` file that is created from my `.tex` file.  When I look at the `.toc` file, it looks correct.  This is part of the code.

```
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {2.1.2}Form}{11}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {2.1.2.1}Morphology}{11}
```

The `subsubsection` doesn't print.  I've tried it with and without the numbers after `\numberline` on `subsubsecction`.  Doesn't make a difference.

What can I do to get all of my headings to be listed in the TOC?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: See [How to show in TOC subcontents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-in-toc-subcontents), which seems to be a duplicate. Please tell us if you need further help with this topic by editing your question accordantly. Otherwise please tell use, then I close this question as a duplicate (no problem!) to keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 7):

The tocdepth counter controls how deep the table of contents goes, and defaults to 3 (subsections). The secnumdepth counter controls which levels of the ToC get numbered. [LaTeX Wikibook reference here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Section_numbering). MWE with numbering and ToC entries given to the paragraph level:

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection One}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection One}
\paragraph{Paragraph One}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this question will most likely by closed as duplicate. See my above link. Now that you have an up-voted answer I might merge both together to keep all answers on the same page.