# How do I make sections in level 4 appear in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show in TOC subcontents?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-in-toc-subcontents)

In my document I have topics that goes four levels deep. That is I have chapters, sections , subsections, subsubsections. My problem is subsubsections does not appear in the generated table of contents. Any ideas on resolving this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

to your preamble.
To have them numbered

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```