# Where should I insert \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}?

Tags: sectioning

I am writing a thesis using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}`.
However, `\subsubsection` is not getting numbered. So on searching in TeX I
got an answer to insert `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`.

Please tell me where to insert `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Commands like this belong into the *preamble*, i.e. between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. If you want your `\subsubsection`s also to be appear in the table of contents you should add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` as well. 
Please see [How to show subsections and subsubsections in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17879/2975) for more information about this, including a list of sectioning levels and their numbers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

%\usepackage{...}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}
Text ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help me to right align the chapter heading also

Comment: In this case please click on the tick-mark on the upper right to accept this answer and conclude this question. You can also wait for more answers or accept another answer later if you want.

Comment: About the chapter header: Please post a new question using the 'Ask Question' button above, after using the search to check if that question was already asked. There should always be only one question per thread on this site.