# Hide subsubsections in toc, but show in PDF

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am hiding subsubsections in my TOC because they got too many. But I would like them to show up in the navigation when viewing the document as PDF anyway. Is there any way to do this, and how?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,pdfstartview={FitB},bookmarksopen,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's what I'm using to thide them from the TOC. But I want them to show up in the PDF anyway

Comment: I was misreading your question. Sorry!

Comment: Related Question: [How to show subsections and subsubsections in TOC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsections-and-subsubsections-in-toc).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=3]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is golden! Now I can even set that to 4, so the paragraphs show up, too, while still keeping the TOC clean and small. Thank you so much! :)