# How can beamer subsubsections have level 4 in PDF bookmarks?

Tags: beamer, xetex, hyperref, pdf, bookmarks

When using beamer, I found that my subsubsections are not shown in the PDF bookmarks.

I can use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` or `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}` to fix it. And I wonder why.

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228740), it’s said that:

> Since `subsubsections` are on level 4, the tocdepth must be set to 4.

But we know subsubsections are of level 3, this image is from `latex2e.pdf`, page 38:

[image]

Furthermore, I found that the PDF bookmarks seem to be always “one-level-less” than the counter `tocdepth`, because if you use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` to change `tocdepth` to 2, even the bookmarks for subsections disappear.

You can use this MWE to test the behavior of the PDF bookmarks and the TOC.
(I’m using TeX Live 2022, I use `latexmk -xelatex ...` to compile.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4} % this let PDF bookmarks show subsubsections
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % this let TOC frame don't show subsubsections, but also cause subsections not shown in PDF bookmarks
% (try comment both, or comment the former and uncomment the latter)



\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} % TOC frame here!
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{a}
\subsection{aaa}
\subsubsection{aaaaa}
\begin{frame}a\end{frame}
\subsubsection{aaabb}
\begin{frame}a\end{frame}
\subsection{abb}
\subsubsection{abbaa}
\begin{frame}a\end{frame}
\subsubsection{abbbb}
\begin{frame}a\end{frame}
\section{b}
\subsection{baa}
\subsubsection{baaaa}
\begin{frame}a\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

beamer changes the numbers. It assigns 1 to part, 2 to section. You can find the relevant code in beamerbasesection.sty, e.g:

```
% in the \part definition
 \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@part}{#1}{Outline\the\c@part}{1}{toc}%

% in \beamer@@section
 \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to ask further that is `\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}` a good solution to the question? Also, is this change mentioned in beamer’s user guide? How were the codes implemented so that I can use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{...}` as usual, i.e., maps subsections to level 2 but not level 3? Is there a reasonable answer to explain why didn’t beamer also change hyperref’s `bookmarksdepth`? I appreciate your answer.