# renumbering paragraphs

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I've tried to renumber `paragraph` refering to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsections-and-subsubsections-in-toc).
Using these lines :

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alpha{paragraph}}
\begin{document}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/cu_raff_majPt}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}
\end{figure}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cas d'utilisation} & Ajouter poste de travail. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Acteur(s)} & Superviseur de l'exploitation Informatique. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Pré-condition} & Utilisateur identifié et autorisé. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Post-condition} & Poste de travail est ajouté avec succ\`es. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Scénario principal} & \begin{enumerate}
\item Le superviseur saisit les données du poste de travail (adresse IP, version et domaine, numéro du si\`ege puis confirme sa saisie.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Le syst\`eme vérifie la saisie et l'existence du poste de travail.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Si les données sont valides et le poste de travail exite réellement et n'est pas déj\`a stocké dans la base de données, le syst\`eme enregistre l'opération d'ajout.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Le syst\`eme affiche un message de succ\`es.
\end{enumerate} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Exceptions} & Si le poste de travail n'existe pas réellement ou exite déj\`a dans la base de données, une erreur est générée. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description textuelle du cas d'utilisation \og Ajouter poste de travail \fg.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/cu_raff_stats}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}
\end{figure}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cas d'utilisation} & Consulter statistiques. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Acteur(s)} & \begin{itemize} \item[-] Superviseur de l'exploitation Informatique.\item[-] Serveur d'applications. 
\end{itemize} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Pré-condition} & Utilisateur identifié et autorisé. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Post-condition} & Statistiques affichée selon selon le type de graphique sélectionné. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Scénario principal} & \begin{enumerate} 
\item Le superviseur sélectionne le type de graphique \`a visualiser (Histogramme, courbe, cercle) ,saisie l'adresse IP du poste de travail et saisie la date de début et la date de fin.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Si la période choisie et l'adresse IP de la station de travail sont valides, le syst\`eme affiche les données adéquates.
\end{enumerate} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Exceptions} & Si la période ou l'adresse IP du poste de travail est/sont invalide, le syst\`eme affiche un message d'erreur. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description textuelle du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/cu_raff_rechercher}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des applications métiers \fg.}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des 0applications métiers \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/cu_raff_arborescence}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des applications métiers \fg.}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/cu_raff_docsSpe}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg.}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Diagramme de paquetage}
\end{document}
```

But this wouldn't compile, I get about 35 errors. How can I achieve that, please ?
I've got the same issue using `\paragraph{Context}`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\alph{paragraph}`; but then you must use `\paragraph{Context}` anyway. And it wouldn't be numbered if you don't also say `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` in the preamble.

Comment: yeah sure, I've juste fogot to copy-past that. I've just edited my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}
```

and not

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alpha{paragraph}}
```

Your code has a spurious "a" in the second line (you are using `\alpha{...}` and it should be `\alph{...})`.

A complete working example with the code snippet provided in the question (I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` to replace the actual images with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/cu_raff_majPt}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}
\end{figure}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cas d'utilisation} & Ajouter poste de travail. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Acteur(s)} & Superviseur de l'exploitation Informatique. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Pré-condition} & Utilisateur identifié et autorisé. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Post-condition} & Poste de travail est ajouté avec succ\`es. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Scénario principal} & \begin{enumerate}
\item Le superviseur saisit les données du poste de travail (adresse IP, version et domaine, numéro du si\`ege puis confirme sa saisie.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Le syst\`eme vérifie la saisie et l'existence du poste de travail.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Si les données sont valides et le poste de travail exite réellement et n'est pas déj\`a stocké dans la base de données, le syst\`eme enregistre l'opération d'ajout.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Le syst\`eme affiche un message de succ\`es.
\end{enumerate} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Exceptions} & Si le poste de travail n'existe pas réellement ou exite déj\`a dans la base de données, une erreur est générée. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description textuelle du cas d'utilisation \og Ajouter poste de travail \fg.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/cu_raff_stats}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}
\end{figure}

\begingroup
\setlength{\LTleft}{-20cm plus -1fill}
\setlength{\LTright}{\LTleft}
\begin{longtable}{|p{3cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Cas d'utilisation} & Consulter statistiques. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Acteur(s)} & \begin{itemize} \item[-] Superviseur de l'exploitation Informatique.\item[-] Serveur d'applications. 
\end{itemize} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Pré-condition} & Utilisateur identifié et autorisé. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Post-condition} & Statistiques affichée selon selon le type de graphique sélectionné. \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Scénario principal} & \begin{enumerate} 
\item Le superviseur sélectionne le type de graphique \`a visualiser (Histogramme, courbe, cercle) ,saisie l'adresse IP du poste de travail et saisie la date de début et la date de fin.\vspace{0.1cm}
\item Si la période choisie et l'adresse IP de la station de travail sont valides, le syst\`eme affiche les données adéquates.
\end{enumerate} \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Exceptions} & Si la période ou l'adresse IP du poste de travail est/sont invalide, le syst\`eme affiche un message d'erreur. \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\[-7pt]  
\caption[]{Description textuelle du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg.}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{images/cu_raff_rechercher}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des applications métiers \fg.}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des 0applications métiers \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{images/cu_raff_arborescence}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des applications métiers \fg.}
\end{figure}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill{}\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{images/cu_raff_docsSpe}\hfill{}
\caption{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg.}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Diagramme de paquetage}
\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, have you tried it putting it in my code, please ? Because, there is always some misetkes that I can not find.

Comment: @user3212730 See my updated answer. I provided a preamble for your document and, as you can see, the document produced the PDF output without problems. Try with the exact code I just posted; do you still get errors, if so, which ones?