# How many levels of nested subsections can the article class support?

Tags: sectioning, document-classes

How many nested subsections can I create using article class in LaTeX? E.g. for first level I use `\subsection`, for second level I use `\subsubsection`. My question is how deep can I go?

Comment: More than the level it starts to make no sense to human readers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default the article supports only the

- \part
- \section
- \subsection
- \subsubsection

as well as `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`. It *is* possible to add additional sections but you should check if it's not easier to switch the class. Here's an example how it may look like (taken from my [blog post](http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=1074), uses the KomaScript `scrartcl` class):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{subsubsubsection}[9em]{}{\contentslabel{3.9em}}%
{\hspace*{-1.2em}}{\titlerule*[0.675pc]{.}\contentspage}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\setcounter{subsubsubsection}{1}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsubsection}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{\sf}{\thetitle}{0.9em}{}[]                       
\titlespacing{\subsubsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus 0.2ex}{1.5ex plus 0.2ex}

\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}%
    {\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}%
    {\parindent}%
    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {-1em}%
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\toclevel@subsubsubsection}{4}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@paragraph}{5}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@subparagraph}{6}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Hier die Section}
\subsection{Hier die eine Sub-Section}
\subsubsection{Hier die SubSub-Section}
\subsubsubsection{Hier die neue SubSubSub-Section} Hallo Welt
\paragraph{Hier der Paragraph} Hallo Welt
\subparagraph{Hier der Sub-Paragraph} Hallo Welt

\section{Hier die Section}
\subsection{Hier die eine Sub-Section}
\subsubsection{Hier die SubSub-Section}
\subsubsubsection{Hier die neue SubSubSub-Section} Hallo Welt
\paragraph{Hier der Paragraph} Hallo Welt
\subparagraph{Hier der Sub-Paragraph} Hallo Welt
\end{document}
```

As you see lots of definitions needed to be made and I am not 100\% sure I got them all.

Comment: Remark: I cannot really recommend this as it leaves a few things untouched that should be modified as well. The KOMA classes have better support, in DTK 3/2017 there is a German article on this topic.

Answer (score 15):

The default [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) provides the following levels of sectioning

- `\part` (level 0)
- `\section` (level 1)
- `\subsection` (level 2)
- `\subsubsection` (level 3)
- `\paragraph` (level 4)
- `\subparagraph` (level 5)

If you wish to add levels below this, see [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below `\subsubsection`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/5764).

Note that more levels are rarely required, since one can always default to lists to provide nested/deeper levels of enumeration.

Comment: I believe part and chapter are book only?

Comment: @vonbrand: `\chapter` is [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) only, but `\part` is also available in [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls).

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply and for your link to the post. The problem I had using that approach was that paragraph was not showing in ToC

Comment: @user3166042: For this you need to adjust `tocdepth`. See [How to show `\subsections` and `\subsubsections` in ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17877/5764)

Comment: the `article` link is a 404 as of 29/03/18

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo: Yes, it used to be on CTAN. They are available from TUG though: [`article`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co), [`book`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls?view=co), [`report`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls?view=co)