# How to exclude paragraph titles in a table of contest?

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs

I'm using the BOOK class, where `\tableofcontents` command seems that include always the `subsubsection` and `paragraph` titles too

How can I exclude the latter?

thanks in advance
Dom

Comment: There must be some reference to changing the value of `tocdepth` in your preamble. You can try `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`...

Comment: Related: [How to show subsections and subsubsections in ToC?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17877/5764)

Comment: @Werner Is this a dupe or do you want to answer?