# Section Numbers in Table of Contents using turabian-formatting

Tags: table-of-contents

I am currently writing my dissertation in latex using turabian-formatting's thesis class, https://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting. By default, the class does not show section and subsection numbers. I have figured out how to get it to show these by commenting out the line in the package that disables them. However, in the table of contents it now tries to write the section (and subsection) numbers *over* the names, making a mess. Here is the (I think) relevant part of the package that controls how the table of contents looks:

```
\renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
\addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
\setlength\@tempdima{1.25in}%
\vskip 1\baselineskip
{   \parindent \z@
\rightskip \@tocrmarg
\parfillskip -\rightskip
\leavevmode
\advance\leftskip\@tempdima
\hskip -\leftskip
#1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
\penalty\@highpenalty}
\fi}

\renewcommand*{\l@section}{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@ \vskip \tf@singlelineskip \fi

\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5in}{\z@}}

\renewcommand*{\l@subsection}{%
\ifnum \c@tocdepth >1 \vskip \tf@singlelineskip \fi
\@dottedtocline{2}{1.75in}{\z@}}
```

Sadly, this is all Greek to me. The chapters look fine in the table of contents. Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix the section and subsection formattings so that it displays properly?

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- add an short compilable code resulting in your issue. That is called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: [Crosspost](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=32219&p=108079#p108074)

Answer (score 1):

The `secnumdepth` value determines to which level section and subsection headings are numbered. The `tocdepth` values determines to which level the table of contents will typeset section and subsection headings (See [How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsubsections-and-paragraphs-in-toc)).

For the [`turabian-thesis`](https://ctan.org/pkg/turabian-formatting) document class, use the `setcounter` command to change the `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` values to '2' in the preamble of your latex document source file (instead of modifying the `turabian-thesis.cls` file). To do so, place the following code *before* `\begin{document}`:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

To adjust how section and subsection entries are typeset in the table of contents, change the values used by `@dottedtocline` command in both the `l@section` and `l@subsection` commands. To do so, renew both the `l@section` and `l@subsection` commands by also placing the following code in your document preamble (the actual values serving as a suggestion):

```
\makeatletter
    \renewcommand*{\l@section}{%
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@ \vskip \tf@singlelineskip \fi
        \@dottedtocline{1}{1.25in}{0.5in}}
    \renewcommand*{\l@subsection}{%
        \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@ \vskip \tf@singlelineskip \fi
        \@dottedtocline{2}{1.75in}{0.5in}}
\makeatother
```

With this, the numbers should now precede the section and subsection headings in the table of contents.