# why \subparagraph in text does not appear in Table of Content and no numbering?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, section-titles

```
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\paragraph{paragraph}
\subparagraph{subparagraph}
```

Outcome:

[image]
[image]

Why in table of content or text as

```
1.1.1.1.1 subparagraph
```

I am using document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
```

Comment: The counter `tocdepth` determines the level down to which sectioning depth entries are shown in the Table of Contents. Its defalt value is usually set by the document class. Do please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico, I am using `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book} `, let me know is this the document class you mean

Comment: Do please check if the posting [How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17877/5001) answers your question.

Comment: @Mico, thanks. `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}`.