# How to enter numbering in all subsections?

Tags: table-of-contents, texmaker

I am trying to create contents of a document and I am facing problem with numbering the `subsubsection{}` part. I am getting the following contents:

[image]

I want the `subsubsections` to be numbered like **1.1.1.1**, **1.2.1.1** and so on in case I enter more of them. Below is the latex script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Section 1}
    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}
    \section{Section 2}
    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you want `x.x.1.x`?

Comment: Add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` to your preamble.

Comment: Yes, and in general If I insert more chapters, I would like x.x.x.x !

Comment: Please clarify the desired numbering scheme. Do you want the `x.x.x.x` to stand for `chapter.section.subsection.subsubsection` or something different?

Comment: @leandriis This numbers them but doesn't insert them into the table of contents. I want this style: `chapter.section.subsection.subsubsection`

Comment: To also add them to the toc, add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`.

Comment: See also: [How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17877/134144)

Comment: Well, problem solved and thank you also for the reference!

Comment: I have voted to close your question as a duplicate to  [How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsubsections-and-paragraphs-in-toc)