# Showing Sections and Subsections in Table of Contents using LaTeX tufte-book document class

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, tufte-book

I can't figure out how to get the sections and subsections to show up in the Table of Contents (TOC) in the tufte-book class.  This template/PDF states on page 28 that the option [notoc] forces the class to revert back to a standard LaTeX TOC:

https://v1.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-design-inspired-by-edward-tufte/gcfbtdjfqdjh.pdf

Yet, I have tried that on both MiKTeK and Overleaf and it is just not the case.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Increase the value of `tocdepth` and `secnumdepth`. The `tocdepth`
> value determines to which level the sectioning commands are printed in
> the ToC (they are always included in the `.toc` file but ignored
> otherwise). The `secnumdepth` value determines up to what level the
> sectioning titles are numbered. They are LaTeX counters and you can
> set them using `\setcounter`.

From [How to show sections and subsections in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17879/161015)

Using

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{tufte-book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

....
```

will output (for `sample-book.tex`)

[image: a]

The `notoc` option suppresses the Tufte-**style** of the table of contents.

Now using with the same file

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[notoc]{tufte-book}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

....
```

the result is

[image: c]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/161015/simon-dispa  EXCELLENT ANSWER AND RESONSE!  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The value of the [tocdepth](https://latex2e.org/Sectioning.html) counter decides which levels of outline are output. It is set to 0 in the tufte-book.cls class file. Change the value of the counter in your preamble to get the output you want. This seems to be independent of whether you set the notoc option or not.