# Paragraphs shown in TOC (documentclass scrbook)

Tags: table-of-contents, sections-paragraphs, scrbook

I am trying to include paragraphs in my table of contents. I believe the reason ehy I did not find any solution yet is my documentclass:

\documentclass[
a4paper,
fontsize=12pt,
openright,
twoside,
listof=totocnumbered,
bibliography=totoc,
pointlessnumbers
]{scrbook}

I use one main.tex file, which uses \include to include other tex files, which contain the actual sections and paragraphs.

How do I make paragraphs show up in my toc (having a subsubsubsection would also work for me)?

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show subsubsections and paragraphs in TOC?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsubsections-and-paragraphs-in-toc) i.e. when you also read [my comment there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17877/how-to-show-subsubsections-and-paragraphs-in-toc/17879#comment1724759_17879).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, fontsize=12pt, openright, twoside, listof=totocnumbered, bibliography=totoc, pointlessnumbers ]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
% 1 = chapter
% 2 = section
% and so on
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{chapter1}
\section{section1}
\subsection{subsection1}
\subsubsection{subsubsection1}
\paragraph{paragraph1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem has been solved! I have marked the respective answer!